# Trimming alphanumeric characters from a strings of varying lengths in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a result set that I want to trim a 2 digit suffix from. The strings will always be of varying lengths, but the suffixes will always be two digits separated by '-'.

Example:

APPTR-W302-01
NRSB-8920-09

Right now I am using the following. This is a hack because the '20' parameter is arbitrary.

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(COURSENAME),4,20))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Will the suffix always be '-##' ? If the suffix length doesn't change,

```
Left(COURSENAME,LEN(COURSENAME)-3)
```

Comment: 2 should be 3 assuming he doesn't want the dash either.

Comment: Right, the suffix length will not change, and yes Otis, I don't need the '-'.

Answer (score 1):

The following code shows three methods that are functionally equivalent in T-SQL.  IMHO the "LEFT" method is the most readable.

```
   DECLARE @courseName VARCHAR(20)
   SET @courseName = 'APPTR-W302-01' -- we need to trim the trailing 2 digits and dash

   SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(@courseName, 1, LEN(@courseName) - 3), 
        LEFT(@courseName, LEN(@courseName) - 3), 
        REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@courseName),4,20))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t varchar(30)
set @t='1234-5678-99'
select right(@t, 2)
```

Comment: That returns the suffix which is what he wants to remove, not keep.